# List of push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Can I get list of my app push notifications from native Notification Center app? When the my app starts, I want to show notifications which were received while my app is not running.

Comment: You want to keep some data within app which comes along with push notification ( when app in not running ) and show though push notification data when user open an app, right ?

Comment: Absolutely right. That's what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can get list of notifications with **iOS 10**

For this you have method in `UNUserNotificationCenter`

```
// Notifications that have been delivered and remain in Notification Center. 
open func getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: @escaping ([UNNotification]) -> Swift.Void)
```

And do it like this

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: { (notifications) in
      // do what you whant with the notifications array
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start your app from the icon, you can't get notifications

You can get one when you click the notification to start your app

Comment: That's not what he's asking.

Comment: it is the answer... it is what I reinforced in my answer but this is correct: "
If you start your app from the icon, you can't get notifications " ==> this is your answer @mattson

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to miss any notification.

You can use Pushkit silent push notification.

Once you receive pushkit payload and your app you can schedule local notification and also keep in `NSUserDefault`.

Using silent push notification your app will be active in background even app is in terminated state. It will be active upto your local notification sound plays ( Max 30 seconds ). You can also keep data in `SQLite` in that duration.

Once you open app from icon or from notification you can check your `NSUserDefauls` or `SQLite` and do further things.

**Note** - With normal push notification, your app would get active in background or terminated state, so you can not write any code to keep data within app which cam along with push notification

**Reference** - https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: Thank you for info . Now I will try to deal with PushKit.

Comment: Check my updated answer, Don't forget to accept answer if helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer & link.

Comment: Welcome, let me know if you get stuck anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as said by Tian:

there is no api to get a list of notifications your app missed.

**no way.**

---

you only get the one the user clicked to launch your app.

Comment: this is true for remote pushes as well as local ones.

Comment: Thank you for your reply